# VBA Code, How to change a specific word from Uppercase to Lowercase in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, uppercase, lowercase

I have an Excel spreadsheet of addresses. I want to change some words into lowercase (rather than the whole cell!). Those words are:

- TH to th (street name)
- 3RD to 3rd
- 2ND to 2nd
- 1ST to 1st

I know how to change the whole cell to lowercase or "Propercase" but I really need a function to change those improper uppercase to lowercase.

Comment: Are you looking for a function to do this or is a replace all good enough ? match exact , don't match entire cell, search in formulas

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to do a find and replace like Holmes IV said. CTRL+F, then click the replace tab. The settings below should work. [image]

Comment: Thank you Kurt! the Fastest way

Answer (score 0):

If you just have those three options:

```
Function ChangeCase(cellinfo As String)

ChangeCase = Replace(Replace(Replace(cellinfo, "1ST", "1st"), "2ND", "2nd"), "3RD", "3rd")

End Function
```